# Confusion of implementing ++iterator and iterator++

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator

When we implement iterator for a linked list class, we have:

```
Iterator operator++(int) { // for itr++
    Iterator old = *this;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    return old;
}

Iterator& operator++() {   // for ++itr
   ptr = ptr->next;
   return *this;
}
```

I am confused of:

1. Why the first one is for itr++ and the second one is for ++itr? How can our compiler differentiate them and choose the right version?
2. Iterator operator++(int): what does the type "int" in the () mean?
3. Why for the first method, we return by value while the second one return by reference?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: 1. Because that's how C++ works, and your compiler is very smart. 2. It means "not the other one". 3. Because that's how iterators are supposed to work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "Because that's how it is" is a poor explanation.

Comment: lol...I am a rookie, and I know this is a stupid question, especially for so many experts in this forum. I am just confused of this and did not find a satisfactory answer to it...Anyway

Comment: C++ is arguably one of the most complicated modern programming languages in use. And it's gotten several times more complicated just the last couple of years. I've been working professionally for +20 years, and I still learn new things, all the time. Just keep reading your C++ book, until you figure it out.

Comment: The `int` is there so the compiler can differentiate between the pre- and post-fix functions.

Comment: @ldytmac You may find this website useful in your C++ journey: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec)

Comment: @ChrisStathis but "that's how it is" is the only answer in this case. You could be more technical and point to the spot in the standard that states it more precisely, but it boils down to the same thing. The question already demonstrates a knowledge of the rules.

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure why this question is attracting downvotes, it's a reasonable thing to ask even if there's no satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the first one is for itr++ and the second one is for ++itr?

Because that's the order you presented them in.

> How can our compiler differentiate them and choose the right version?

One has a parameter of type `int`, the other one has no parameters.

> what does the type "int" in the () mean?

There needs to be some way for the compiler to determine whether you are trying to overload the prefix version of `operator++`, or the postfix version. This is the syntax that does that. An `operator++` with an `int` parameter is postfix, and with no parameters is prefix. Same goes for `operator--`.

> Why for the first method, we return by value while the second one return by reference?

In the first method, you are returning a new object which is created locally in the function. This object will be destroyed when the function ends. If you returned it by reference, it would be a dangling reference. So you need to return it by value.

With the second method, you are returning the same object which is being incremented. It is not local to the function. It is the instance upon which the method is being called. So you can return it by reference. You don't have to. But that is the convention.